How would I correctly add dynamic pages to a Gravity forms Form?
I'm attempting to hook into the gravity_forms_prerender hook to add dynamically generated pages to a form. The form has a page set up in the gravity forms UI. Using PHP I'm attempting to add a variable amount of pages based on a variable set up elsewhere (it just returns an integer). My problem is that when I complete the first page and click on the next button the form automatically goes to the confirmation page. Heres my code:

add_pages($form) {
       //...Setup Code
        $breakfast = get_field('breakfast_menu', 'option');
        $dinner = get_field('dinner_menu', 'option');
        for ($guest_index = 0; $guest_index < $guests_count; $guest_index++) {
          $page_break = new GF_Field_Page();
          $page_break->title = "Meal Selection for Guest " . ($guest_index + 1);

          $field_exists = false;
          $page_id = 'guest_' . $guest_index . '_meal_selection';
          foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
              if ($field->id == $page_id) {
                  $field_exists = true;
                  break;
              }
          }
          $page_break->type = "page";
          $page_break->id = $page_id;
          $page_break->pageNumber = $guest_index + 2;
          $form['pagination']['pages'][] =  $page_break->title;
          $page_break->displayOnly = false;
          $form['fields'][] = $page_break;

          $text_field = new GF_Field_Text();
          
          // Add meal selection form for guest
          $html_field = new GF_Field_HTML();
          $html_field->displayOnly = false;
          $html_field->id = 'guest_' . $guest_index . '_meal_selection_fields';
          $html_content = $this->get_meal_selection_menu(
              $guest_index,
              $breakfast,
              $dinner,
              $nights_count,
              $additional_breakfasts_count,
              $additional_dinners_count
          );
          $html_field->content = $html_content;
          $form['fields'][] = $html_field;
      }
   return $form;
}

add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_23', 'add_pages');

